# Finding limit of [x]{x} when 'x' tends to 0.

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I calculated **$\lim_{x\to 0}$ [x]{x}** as follows ({x} and [x] mean fractional part function and greatest integer function respectively):-
$$\lim_{x\to 0} [x]\{x\}$$
To find the **right hand limit**, I replaced 'x' by $0+h$ where $h>0$ and ${h\to 0^+}$. Hence we get,
$$\lim_{h\to 0^+} [0+h]\{0+h\}$$
As ${h\to 0^+}$ and $h>0$,${0+h\to 0}$ and hence $[0+h]=0$.

And again, as ${h\to 0^+}$, $\{0+h\}=h$. So we get the right hand limit as,
$$\lim_{h\to 0^+} (0*h)=0$$

To find the **left hand limit** I replaced 'x' by $0-h$ where $h>0$ and ${h\to 0^-}$. Hence we get,
$$\lim_{h\to 0^-} [0-h]\{0-h\}$$
Now we will get $[-h]=-1$ because $h>0$ and ${h\to 0}$.

Also, $\{-h\}=1-h$. So we get the left hand limit as,
$$\lim_{h\to 0} (-1\cdot(1-h))=-1$$

This means RHL and LHL are not equal and hence the limit of the function doesn't exist when ${x\to 0}$.But the correct answer is that it does and is equal to $0$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Do you mean $x^x$. You need to approach $x\rightarrow 0^+$,.

Comment: Idon't see any mistake: actually the right limit is $0$, while the left limit is $-1$.

Comment: @vitamind As 'h' is positive and ${h\to 0}$, assume it to be equal to 0.000001 for example, that means $-h=-0.000001$ and $[-0.000001]=-1$

Comment: No sorry I have mistaken it foor the ceiling function. Now everything is clear.

Comment: So: either your source has the wrong answer, or you copied the problem incorrectly.  Perhaps $[x]$ and/or $\{x\}$ have unusual definitions: for example, in some computer contexts (and some "scientific" calculators), for $[x]$ you round toward zero instead of rounding down.  Perhaps the reason computer scientists invented the "floor" and "ceiling" notations was that they already had the wrong definition of  "integer part" and could not change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have done is absolutely correct. Another way to see this is that $\{x\} = x - [x]$ and thus, your limit is simply $$\lim_{h \to 0}\left(h[h] - [h]^2\right).$$
The limit of the first term exists since $h \to 0$ and $[h]$ is bounded.
However, the limit of the second term does not exist as $[h]$ is $-1$ on $(-1, 0)$ whereas it is $0$ on $(0, 1)$.

Thus, the overall limit does not exist.

Here's a graph (courtesy of Desmos):
[image]